# Polarity of TVS diode is unclear

Tags: protection, circuit-protection, esd, tvs, polarity

I have a question regarding the [DESD1LIN2WSQ](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DESD1LIN2WSQ.pdf) TVS diode by Diodes Inc. which I want to use to protect some 24V IOs of a microcontroller board.

Until now, the TVS diodes I worked with always had the same characteristic in both directions, but this one doesn't.

What is unclear to me is, how I should communicate the desired polarity to our pcb assembler.

This image from the datasheet clearly shows that polarity matters:

[image: I-V graph]

But I can't figure out which pin is pin 1 and which pin is pin 2.
Those images from the datasheet don't show this clearly:

[image: device schematic]

[image: product marking]

I have not seen this device in real, because our assembler does the sourcing.
Assuming that the device has a "cathode" marking, I'd place the diode this way by intuition:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiqPhy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It might be obvious to an experienced engineer, but I don't want to decide "by intuition", which could waste a whole batch of PCBs.
So, is the above orientation correct?

**Edit 1:**
I found [this document](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Packaging-Support-Docs/ap02007.pdf) with general information about Diodes' SMD packaging. There is this entry for the relevant diode:

[image]

Does this help to determine the correct orientation (e.g. is there a convention like "pin 1 has to be oriented upwards in a reel")?

Comment: Oh wow. Someone dropped the ball on that datasheet. You should message them.

Comment: I'd check the tape & reel info from the datasheet but there's none. Pin-1 or pin-2 should've been marked according to the feed direction, at least. One possible option could be that the assembler should check the marking to determine the placement direction. Hope all the components are placed in the same orientation (Sigh).

Comment: Thanks for the posting. I'll watch out if any of my engineers try to use that weird thing.  It has Vbr1 = 20.3V, Vbr2=30.3. That's gonna be difficult now and trouble in the future.

Comment: @RohatKılıç that's an interesting approach, but I don't know how I would "read" this information. I found a document regarding the general packaging (please view my edit). Is this the information you're refering to?

Comment: @SimSon yes, that's the info I'm referring to. This should've been given in the datasheet. Anyway, the feed direction for P&P machine, according to the image, is left to right. So, initially (i.e. at zero degree of rotation) the mark should look towards the left-hand side. Your component has a mark on it, so I'd expect placement acc. to the top detail. But your component is bidirectional, so let's hope they sticked to the top detail anyways.

Comment: @RohatKılıç So that means that my assumption (pin 1 is "cathode") is correct? Sry, I just want to make sure I understood that correctly - I have few knowledge about how the assembly processworks in practice.

Comment: @SimSon `So that means that my assumption (pin 1 is "cathode") is correct?` looks like so.

Comment: If your 24 V IOs are actually supposed to see 24 V, shouldn't you put the TVS the other way around? The breakdown voltage from pin 1 to 2 is just 20 V. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TooTea hmm, as far as I know, voltage points from negative to positive by convention. So if the diode is oriented like in my drawing, it sees 24V "from pin 2 to pin 1"... do you have a reference for your statement? Maybe I can loose even more confidence in this datasheet ;)

Comment: @SimSon I've never worked with a TVS like this, so they might well be using some special convention, hence my question (perhaps I misunderstood the datasheet). But in general, we talk about current flowing from the positive terminal to the negative, it's just the electrons that actually go the other way.

Comment: @TeeTea true, the question is if "from pin x to pin y" refers to a "voltage-arrow" (which was my assumption) or a current flow through/voltage drop accross the device... you might be right, thanks for pointing that out! I'll have to dive into other LIN-bus protection diodes' datasheets, I guess.

Comment: @SimSon The convention of "voltage points from negative to positive" is not universal; it's the other way around in Europe, for instance, and in the US we don't generally talk about voltage using arrows at all.

Comment: @Hearth I'm actually from Europe and I'm still not certain about this terminology. Following the US convention, how would you orient that diode to protect a 24V line? Pin1 -> 24V and pin2 -> GND?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer from Diodes:
Pin 1 is marked with the bar.

I also had my assembler do a measurement and the correct orientation for my application (i.e. steady 24VDC are expected accross the diode) is:

- the side marked with the bar has to be connected to GND
- the side without marking has to be connected to 24V

Answer (score 4):

Looking at a couple other bidirectional/asymmetrical TVS from [Nexperia](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD1LIN.pdf), [Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85902/vlin1626-02g.pdf), and [ST](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/b3/6c/2c/db/f4/9a/43/1a/CD00131990/files/CD00131990.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00131990.pdf), the stripe indicates pin 1.  I'd test to double check, but it looks like a pretty safe bet that your device is similar.

Comment: Thanks for looking up those diodes! It's becoming more and more likely to me that the way *I* would assemble the diode is correct. I hope to get a response from Diodes, though.

Answer (score 3):

By convention, pin 1 would be marked with the bar.  This is supported by the bar being on the left on one drawing, and pin 1 being on the left on the other.  It's not a guarantee, though; if you have the chance, you could verify it by applying a voltage (~36V) through a series resistor (~27 ohms) and measuring it each way.

Comment: I would normally test it as you said, but the thing is that I don't have such a diode at hand as our assembler did the sourcing... I got in touch with Diodes, hope they will help.